# How to disable facebook automatic greeting message on website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-customer-chat

I inserted the following code into the head tag. This enabled me to get the Facebook Messenger inside my website.

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v7.0'
          });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

      <!-- Your customer chat code -->
      <div class="fb-customerchat"
        attribution=setup_tool
        page_id="XXXXXXXXXX"
  theme_color="#FF5733">
      </div>
```

However, I am not liking the way that the greeting message automatically pops up whenever a page is loaded. How do I disable the automatic messenger greeting?

[image]

Comment: The documentation page for the plugin explains all the options there are.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/#include): "By default, the greeting dialog will be shown on desktop and mobile. To customize the greeting dialog behavior, you can use the greeting_dialog_display and 'greeting_dialog_delay' attributes." The rest you can probably find on your own

Comment: Thanks, solved after adding greeting_dialog_display="hide"

Answer (score 3):

Changed my code to below & it solved the issue.

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v7.0'
          });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

      <!-- Your customer chat code -->
      <div class="fb-customerchat"
        attribution=setup_tool
        page_id="XXXXXXXXXX"
  theme_color="#FF5733"
           greeting_dialog_display="hide">
      </div>
```